# How use checkbox with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

there are checkboxes in record, it is necessary to hook Ajax of their value (noted) both to take through get_post_meta and to obtain data from this field and to remove through a comma in other field(id=parsing_night_key)?

```
function lft_checkbox_meta() {
    add_meta_box(
        'lft-checkbox',
        __( 'Отели', 'undefined' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'parsing',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'lft_checkbox_meta' );

function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

    $checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "checkfield", true) );

    wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' ); 

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 0,
        'post_type'   => 'hotel'
    );
    $hotels = get_posts($args);

    foreach ( $hotels as $page ) { ?>
        <input id="need_check" type="checkbox" name="checkfield[]" value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php if ( in_array($page->ID, (array) $checkfield) ) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/> <label for="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></label> <br>
<?php 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Kentos and welcome to StackOverFlow. Can you please explain a bit what you want to achieve ? It's unclear for now

Comment: I want to take all checkboxes which are active. Checkboxes (posts from other any record) in them are fields, and they need to be taken and inserted into other field